# Return a string outside of a class or function with Python

Tags: python

I'm new to OOP and am trying to figure out how to get the result of something outside of a class in order to decide what to do next in my program.

I'm unzipping a file, and if it takes too long then I want the process to terminate. This code will do just that:

```
class Command(object):
    def __init__(self,cmd):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.process = None

    def run(self,timeout):
        def target():
            print("Thread started")
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd)
            self.process.communicate()
            print("Thread finished")

        thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
        thread.start()

        thread.join(timeout)
        if thread.is_alive():
            print("\nTerminating process")
            self.process.terminate()
            thread.join()            
        print(self.process.returncode)

def unzip_file(file,dirout,attempt):
    just_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]    
    print('unzip started at {} for {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now(),file))
    command = Command(zip_exe+' x '+file+' -o'+path+dirout)
    command.run(timeout = 300)
```

...but what if I wanted to get the the command output, outside of the function that was called inside the Class? Say to a variable called 'tmp'. I've added two annotated lines to illustrate what I'm trying to do which of course returns an error.

```
class Command(object):
    def __init__(self,cmd):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.process = None

    def run(self,timeout):
        def target():
            print("Thread started")
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd)
            self.tmp = self.proc.stdout.read() #get the command line output
            self.process.communicate()
            print("Thread finished")

        thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
        thread.start()

        thread.join(timeout)
        if thread.is_alive():
            print("\nTerminating process")
            self.process.terminate()
            thread.join()            
        print(self.process.returncode)

def unzip_file(file,dirout,attempt):
    just_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]    
    print('unzip started at {} for {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now(),file))
    command = Command(zip_exe+' x '+file+' -o'+path+dirout)
    command.run(timeout = 300)
    print(self.tmp)    #print the command line output (doesn't work)
```

Comment: Why don't you `print(self.tmp)` inside `target`?

Comment: Because I want to use the string elsewhere in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `self.tmp = self.proc.stdout.read()` puts some data into a member variable. You can then use it outside of the class by simple using a reference to the object:

```
...
command.run(timeout = 300)
print(command.tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that the identifier `self` is not defined in function `unzip_file`. Try  replacing

```
print(self.tmp)    #print the command line output (doesn't work)
```

with

```
print(command.tmp)
```

Identifier `self` has a special meaning when used in the scope of a class and refers to the instance of that class. When used elsewhere (as in `unzip_file`), the identifier has no special meaning and is just a regular undefined identifier.

Aside from your actual problem, you might want to research communication mechanisms between threads. [Queue module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) is a good place to look at if you already understand the basics. If you are new to the topic, then [this one](http://www.slideshare.net/dabeaz/an-introduction-to-python-concurrency) is a decent introduction.